# warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: mysql, c, int, warnings

Tenho o seguinte código em C que faz uma conexão com um banco de dados mysql e realiza uma query:

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    MYSQL Connection;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    mysql_init(&Connection);

    if(mysql_real_connect(&Connection, "127.0.0.1", "root", "xururuca", "test", 0, NULL, 0)){

        printf("Connection: Ok...\n\n");

    }else{

        printf("Error in connection\n\n");
    }

    mysql_query(&Connection ,"select id from accounts where username='Alan' and password='lixodoesgotogostoso';");

    res=mysql_store_result(&Connection);

    row=mysql_fetch_row(res);

    printf("%s\n", row[0]); //ele imprime 3 (Ok...)

    int userID=row[0]; //Agora tento passar esse 3 para uma variável do tipo int...mais não rola

    printf("%d\n", userID); //Imprime lixo e não 3 que seria o correto

    mysql_free_result(res);
    mysql_close(&Connection);

    return 0;
}
```

Quando compilo: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|

Então, eu quero que meu 'result set' vá para a variável userID, mais como eu faço isso sem maiores problemas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repare que o `printf` funciona mas o formatador é `%s`. Isso significa que o valor que tem em `row[0]` é na verdade uma `string`, ou sendo mais exato, um ponteiro para um array de carateres. Uma vez que é um ponteiro o compilador queixa-se pois está a guarda-lo num `int`.

Pode também [confirmar na documentação que MYSQL_ROW é um array de strings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-data-structures.html)

Para converter o valor da string em inteiro pode utilizar a função [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/):

```
int userID = atoi(row[0]);
```